# CAML query to show _moderationstatus

Tags: jquery, caml-query

I am trying to show list items in a publishing page and I am getting all column values except for `Approval Status` column which should show text as values is showing integers like  0 for Approved instead of approved. I am using jQuery and CAML to get the other values. How to get the `_ModerationStatus` value as text in jQuery using CAML for SharePoint 2010 list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, the value of the _`ModerationStatus` is stored as numbers, corresponding the values in the [SPModerationStatusType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationstatustype.aspx).

You can translate the numerical values by defining your own moderationStatusType array in JavaScript as shown below:

```
var moderationStatusType = [ "Approved", "Denied", "Pending", "Draft", "Scheduled" ];

var modStatAsNumber = 0;
var modStatAsText = moderationStatusType[modStatAsNumber];
```

Comment: Pholpar that worked like a charm thanks a ton for saving my time...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SP.ListItem.fieldValuesAsHtml property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245983.aspx) to get the values for the list item as HTML, for example:

```
ctx.load(items,'Include(FieldValuesAsHtml)');  //retrieve FieldValuesAsHtml property
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++){
           var item = items.get_item(i);
           var statusText = item.get_fieldValuesAsHtml().get_item('_ModerationStatus');
      }
  },
  error);
```

**Complete example**

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId; //current List Id
getListItems(listId, 
   function(items){
       for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++){
           var item = items.get_item(i);
           var statusText = item.get_fieldValuesAsHtml().get_item('_ModerationStatus');

       }
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

where

```
function getListItems(listId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   ctx.load(items,'Include(FieldValuesAsHtml)');
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(items); 
      },
      error);
}
```